# How many characters can a SQL Query have? OracleDB and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm working on a feature in a Java application that builds a query based on a LOG table.

This LOG table basically has the history of created entities, storing all PK columns and their values.

This feature basically adds an intermediary filter where the user can tell me something like:

"Here are the entity X and date Y. Go to the log table, find all PKs of entity X since the date Y, then go on the Entity X's table and bring me all the data based on the PKs that you've get on the last step."

**This is why I cannot paginate :(. I need to find all PKs since date Y.**

I'm facing the following situation:

Imagine that my log table has 5,000 creation logs of the `TB_WINDOWS` table. The table `TB_WINDOWS` has a composite key with 3 columns `ID(NUMBER), CREATED_BY(NUMBER), CREATED_AT(DATE)`.

So the query will have **at least**:

- At least 10,000 AND clauses (`AND.size()` * 10,000 = 30,000 characters)
- At least 5,000 OR clauses (`OR.size()` * 5,000 = 10,000 characters)
- At least 30,000 `()` braces
- At least 110,000 characters (( `ID.size()` + `CREATED_BY.size()`  + `CREATED_AT.size()` ) * 5,000 = 110,000).

So, imagine the query looking like this:

```sql
-- In this example I'm using Oracle's TO_DATE.
-- But as I said, I need to know about Oracle and SQL Server
-- So, just take this as an example.
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TB_WINDOWS
WHERE
    (ID = 1
        AND CREATED_BY = 2
        AND CREATED_AT = TO_DATE('a date', 'a format') )
    OR (ID = 2
        AND CREATED_BY = 3
        AND CREATED_AT = TO_DATE('a date', 'a format') )
    OR (.....)
    OR (.....)
    OR (.....)
    -- And many other OR clauses
```

We can say that this query will have more than 180,000 characters.

My question is, does ORACLE and SQL Server have a limitation on the number of characters that a SQL Query can have?

Comment: Why are you asking such a thing? It's almost certainly a sign you're doing something wrong. If you want to copy 15K rows from one database to another, either use `INSERT SELECT` if they're somehow linked or export the data from one and import them into the other. Don't generate queries from that data

Comment: Yes, there is a limit to the number of characters that can be passed into OPENQUERY, which is 8,000 characters. You can overcome this by using a declaration, and passing your query statement into it with EXECUTE as described in this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187522/8000-character-limit-on-openquery-against-a-linked-server

Comment: If you need to ask such things, you're almost always Doing it Wrong. In this case, whatever you're doing is probably better done by passing in a table-valued parameter or loading data into a temp table and then joining on that. But if you really want to know, for SQL Server the limit is [64 KB times the network packet size](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server), which would translate to a whopping 256 MB. In practice, the T-SQL parser and/or the optimizer will choke and run out of resources long before that limit is hit.

Comment: In SQL Server you can use SSIS to create an ETL job that reads data from one database and writes it to the other in a streaming manner. There's even a wizard for this in SQL Server's Management Studio in `Import/Export`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I haven't said at any point that I'm trying to copy data between databases. I'm asking if there are any limitations in both SQL Server and Oracle. I even said I want to copy lines. Please read the question before answering.

Comment: @VitorNilson you asked a question that suggests a serious problem. `I'm asking if there are any limitations in both SQL Server and Oracle.` and why are you asking that? If you have to ask how big a raw SQL string can be, something is very, very wrong. It means you're trying to stuff data into the query.  Assume you're talking to a (former) SQL Server MVP who's built data warehouses pulling data from Oracle, SQL Server, and MySQL (I have).  Transferring 1M rows at a time is easy with the right tools.

Comment: If you really want to generate a huge almost unparsable query, you can. You can generate a huge query and save it as a `.sql` file, then try to execute it. Even if this doesn't hit a hard character limit, it will hit into either hard *complexity* limits or take so much time to compile it will time out. It's impossible to guess what that limit will be without looking at the query and knowing the actual hardware and even patch levels of the databases. Even then it may not be possible to predict at what point the query will crash under its own weight

Comment: `15,000 AND clauses` that's data, not clauses. Instead of writing 15K clauses that have to be evaluated one by one, you can insert them into a temporary *and* indexed table and JOIN with any other table you need. Using a JOIN over an index will result in orders of magnitude better performance *and* far less complexity. In turn that means a better execution plan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos cool, congratulations on your achievements. And cool, now you've answered my question. So there's a limitation and there's a workaround that is using temporary tables. Thanks.

Comment: No I haven't, because I still have no idea what you're asking. I said an overly complex query can fail to even get compiled, even if no limits are reached. Temporary tables are just an example for a very specific case. They're *not* a good idea for recurring jobs. A staging table where you can store data for preparation would be better

Comment: How about eliminating the need for 15K conditions? That's also possible using change tracking. You may be able to send only changes to the other database.

Comment: [For Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76): "The limit on how long a SQL statement can be depends on many factors, including database configuration, disk space, and memory" which kind of echos what's already been said about overwhelming the DB parser/resources; clients may have their own logical or resource limits before you reach the DB limits too.

Comment: How about you include an example of the query you're seeking to build, and we can answer with concrete examples of better patterns.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos let me fix this "other database" point, my company works with Oracle and SQL Server. They're an ERP, so some costumers have Oracle and other costumers have SQL Server. I'm not trying to send data between a Oracle and a SQL Server. I'm just trying to know what are the limitations of SQL Server and Oracle SQL because I need to be aware of this, I need to think of implementing a solution that works both in Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: ***Do not*** "think of implementing a solution that works both in Oracle and SQL Server".  They have different symantics, different syntax, different resource controls, different execution plans, different capabilities and limitations.  Tailor you application to be able to utilise different approaches for different platforms.  I could find a fuel that works natively in both Diesel and Petrol Engines, but that would be a poor fuel in ***both*** cases.  Please read this; https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Can you explain why you need to create so many AND's? Maybe we're missing something. How does your query look? Or what are you trying to do? Are you doing something like: "Get me all log posts for these 15k IDs"? In that case, you can convert your IDs to a long CSV String as a SQL parameter to a prepared statement and split it with a STRING_SPLIT on the serverside, simply and easy Otherwise i'm not really with you.

Comment: @siggemannen There's no 15k ids, there's 5k ids that are a composite key with 3 fields. So it's something like: `SELECT * FROM TB_WINDOWS WHERE (ID=1 AND  CREATED_BY = 2 AND CREATED_AT = TO_DATE('a date', 'a format') ) OR (ID=2 AND CREATED_BY = 3 AND CREATED_AT = TO_DATE('a date', 'a format') ) OR ..... `. Prepared statements sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

You risk serious trouble to run your code in production. Oracle shares SQL statements and their exec plan. Therefore every every SQL hard-parsing requires exclusive lock in shared memory resources. This can be a problem when a chunk of memory you want to allocate is HUGE. I saw DB system crashes cased by situation when heavily loaded system tried to allocate memory in shared area, trying to parse 15MB SQL statement.

Generally this approach (used by Hibernate for example) is discouraged.
There were various articles written about "Dynamic where clause problem" in Oracle. It is much safer to store your data in temporary table - for example.

Comment: For this reason the more enterprise-y versions of both Oracle and SQL Server have resource governors that will kill or throttle overly complex or expensive queries. And Oracle DBAs can get very, very vocal

Comment: I'm pretty sure even non-enterpricy (no pun intended) SQL Server query plan creator will crash when trying to parse so many AND condition